# How to reduce MS WPF Ribbon control's transparency?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon, ribbon-control

Default transparency of a MS WPF Ribbon control's instance is too high in Windows 7.
How to reduce MS WPF Ribbon control's transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying BackgroundBrush's transparency seems to do the trick...